# Elementary number theory -Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For arbitrary integers a, b and c, either provide a proof or a counter example.

If a|(b+c), then a|b and a|c

My solution was 
Let counter example
a∤(b+c)
then,

b+c ≠ ma (m in Z)
∴ b ≠ ma-c
∴ a∤b

and c ≠ ma-b
∴ a∤c

Is my solution correct

Comment: A counterexample should be just three actual _integers_ that show the assertion is false.

Comment: By contrast, "If $a\mid (b+c)$, then $(a\mid b) \equiv (a\mid c)$" is true, understanding the "$\equiv$" to mean that the two divisibility claims are either both true or both false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is incorrect. Just because we have that $b$ is not in the form $ma-c$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't mean that it can't be in the form $ma$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ which is what is being said by $a\nmid b$. The first thing you should check when asked to prove or disprove is concrete examples. Let $a=2$ and $b=c=1$, then $a\mid (b+c)$ but $a\nmid b$ and $a\nmid c$ making the claim false.

Comment: b+c = ma (for some m in Z)
∴ b = ma-c    
∴ a∤b
and c = ma-b 
∴ a∤c
Now is it correct

Comment: No, because what if $c=a$, then $b=ma-a=(m-1)a$, so $a\mid b$. There are examples where the claim is true, take say $(a,b,c)=(2,4,4)$. That is why your proof, which tries to prove the converse to be true is false.

Answer (score 1):

With a counter-example you can just provide particular values for $a,b,c$. For example $(a,b,c) = (3,4,5)$ is a counter-example disproving the assertion, since $a \mid b{+}c$ (that is, $3\mid 9$) but $a\nmid b$ and $a\nmid c$.

Comment: Thank you I got the point